# AngularFire authenticating with routers $digest loop error

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am working on a simple application using AngularFire and some routes are protected using [ui-router example](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#ui-router-example) from AngularFire guide.

When the URL is empty, ui-router handles it with `$urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/account');`. But when the redirect URL is protected like:

```
.state('account', {
                    controller: 'AccountCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    url: '/account',
                    templateUrl: 'app/account/account.html',
                    data: {
                        title: '- Account'
                    },
                    resolve: {
                        'currentAuth': ['Auth', function(Auth) {
                            return Auth.$requireSignIn();
                        }]
                    }
                })
```

the error below is thrown:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

Please, could you help me with this annoying error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

> event.preventDefault ()

to halt initial state

```
if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
    //halt default event then initiate state go to new nested page
    event.preventDefault();

    // as of now, we go to login until landing template is up
    $state.go("home");
 }
```

Comment: The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action (goto 'account' state) that belongs to the event will not occur. ui-router is running sync events.  You codes will go to both states 'account' & 'home' even the AUTH_REQUIRED error thrown. Because of that, you will have infinity "AUTH_REQUIRED" errors. So use this code to halt the account state

Answer (score 0):

`Auth.$requireSignIn` will throw an error `AUTH_REQUIRED`. You can try to re-direct to the right state by monitoring `$stateChangeError` where `AUTH_REQUIRED` error is caught.

```
// for ui-router
app.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireSignIn promise is rejected
    // and redirect the user back to the home page
    if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
      $state.go("home");
    }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: this is not the problem. I have this piece of code in my project.

Comment: get it, hope my second answer can help you.